# How to make multiline input in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, console

I'm intrested in **C++** code like this:

```
 while(getline(cin, n))
```

but I want to do this in **C#** and I don't know how to do something like this. I have `10` line input, which needs to be in *one string*, but with `Console.ReadLine()` it only saves me *one line* out of `10` to string. My string variable has to have `10` line text,

**For example:**

```
"first line of text\nsecond line\nthird".
```

Is it any way to do something like this, like in C++?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with Console.ReadLine. What's the rest of your code? Chances are that you always replace the contents of the string.

Comment: If it's always 10 lines then StringBuilder, a for loop, and ReadLine will get you there.

Comment: C# terminal I/O (like Java, C++, C, Python, etc etc) uses [line-oriented I/O](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis1xx/resources/java/fileIO/introToFileIO.html).  That's why Console.Readline() works the way it does.  Your best bet might just be to ReadLine() a line at a time, and concatenate the individual lines into a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to mimic `getline(cin, n)`, you can try reading from *stdin*, i.e.

```
using System.IO;

... 

// Read line by line from stdin
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadStdInLines() {
  using var reader = new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput());

  for (string line = reader.ReadLine(); line != null; line = reader.ReadLine())
    yield return line;
}
```

For instance:

```
using System.Linq;

...

string[] lines = ReadStdInLines()
  .Take(10) // at most 10 lines
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks Dmitry Bychenko

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize a new variable to indicate the number of lines to enter. Then, in a loop, enter the specified number of new lines. If you do not know when the end of the input data will be, then you can complete the input with [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_String_IsNullOrWhiteSpace_System_String_), which checks whether the last line you entered is empty and this completes the input.
Example:

```
string line;
while(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line=Console.ReadLine())) {}
```

Comment: Also check this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338657/multiple-lines-input-from-console-in-c-sharp)